# Python list of lists to divide an element position on all sublists by a number

Tags: python, list

How can in python take a lists of lists and apply a division to the third element of each sublist.

The sublists looks like this

```
[1.3735876284e-05, 0.9277849431216683, 34.02875434027778, 0.0]
[2.60440773e-06,   7.35174234e-01,   2.79259180e+02,   0.00000000e+00]
...
```

I need to get the same sublists but the third element of each sublist (34.02 ..., 2.79 ...) should be divided by 100

Comment: `for sublist in lists: sublist[2] /= 100`

Comment: `[[e/100 if i == 2 else e for i,e in enumerate(sub)] for sub in some_list]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try this:

```
a = [
    [1.3735876284e-05, 0.9277849431216683, 34.02875434027778, 0.0],
    [2.60440773e-06,   7.35174234e-01,   2.79259180e+02,   0.00000000e+00],
]
b = [
    [(x / 100.0 if i == 2 else x) for (i, x) in enumerate(lst)] 
        for lst in a
]
```

Or the lambda version:

```
f = lambda a: [
    [(x / 100.0 if i == 2 else x) for (i, x) in enumerate(lst)] 
        for lst in a
]
b = f(a)
```

Answer (score 1):

use a list comprehension to extract sub-lists, and use addition to concatenate list parts...

`lambda L: [l[:2]+[l[2]/100]+l[3:] for l in L]`